# Issue storing AVRO Kafka streams to File System

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I want to store my AVRO kafka streams to file system using my spark streaming API with the following scala code in delimited format, but facing some challenges in achieving this

```
record.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).csv("/Users/Documents/kafka-poc/consumer-out/)
```

Since, record(generic record) is not a DF or RDD, I am not sure how to proceed with this?

**Code**

```
       val messages = SparkUtilsScala.createCustomDirectKafkaStreamAvro(ssc, kafkaParams, zookeeper_host, kafkaOffsetZookeeperNode, topicsSet)
       val requestLines = messages.map(_._2) 
       requestLines.foreachRDD((rdd, time: Time) => {
       rdd.foreachPartition { partitionOfRecords => {
       val recordInjection = SparkUtilsJava.getRecordInjection(topicsSet.last)
       for (avroLine <- partitionOfRecords) {
       val record = recordInjection.invert(avroLine).get
       println("Consumer output...."+record)                                                                
       println("Consumer output schema...."+record.getSchema)
       }}}}
```

**following is the output & schema**

```
{"username": "Str 1-0", "tweet": "Str 2-0", "timestamp": 0}
{"type":"record","name":"twitter_schema","fields":[{"name":"username","type":"string"},{"name":"tweet","type":"string"},{"name":"timestamp","type":"int"}]}
```

Thanks in advance and appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this.

```
val jsonStrings: RDD[String] = sc.parallelize(Seq(record.toString())); 
val result = sqlContext.read.json(jsonStrings).toDF(); 
result.write.mode("Append").csv("/Users/Documents/kafka-poc/‌​consumer-out/");
```